# What is bootstrap cdn?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdn

I have no idea about Content Delivery Network with bootstrap. I am working on a website management for my company, this website is done with bootstrap CDN. I have knowledge about bootstrap.  ** Kindly Help me!**

Answer (score 4):

You can find this out just by googling it.  Bootstrap is not the only library that uses CDN's.  Read the the following post for more information or just try googling Content Delivery Network.

[CDN - Content Delivery Network](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html)

A content delivery network (CDN) is a system of distributed servers (network) that deliver webpages and other Web content to a user based on the geographic locations of the user, the origin of the webpage and a content delivery server.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a free and open-source framework. The bootstrap assets (JS, CSS, ...) can be loaded via a CDN but you can also load it from your server (which is slower from a global perspective). Therefore, a CDN is recommended.

Any CDN can be used to deliver the Bootstrap assets. For that matter you can also use a free CDN such as [JSDelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/projects/bootstrap).